# Random image generator not working for discord bot

Tags: javascript, image, random, discord

I've fiddled around with it and still can not get it to work. Also I have tried with a singular image and it worked without problem. Here's my code:

```js
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    var rands = ["./catboy/cb1.jpg","./catboy/cb2.jpg","./catboy/cb3.jpg","./catboy/cb4.jpg"];
    var rand = [Math.floor(Math.random()*(rands.length))];
    message.channel.send("rawr", rand);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly the problem is? What doesn't work?

Comment: it says the message i put in but it does not send the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * rands.length);
```

Than to send the image use

```
message.channel.send("rawr", rands[rand]);
```

Example using some better variable naming:

```js
var images = ["./catboy/cb1.jpg","./catboy/cb2.jpg","./catboy/cb3.jpg","./catboy/cb4.jpg"];
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
var randomImage = images[rand];

console.log( randomImage ) // The one to send
// message.channel.send("rawr", randomImage);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything for me Could it have something to do with my files?

Comment: @Andrew perhaps your paths are wrong `./` I don't know. The example now works as expected - you need to check for errors in console.

Comment: well in console it shows "./catboy/cb3.jpg" but no picture is popping up on discord

Comment: @Andrew have you uncommented the `// message.channel.send("rawr", randomImage);` ? Place those 5 lines inside your `exports.run` and uncomment the last line.

Comment: like this? `exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    var images = ["./catboy/cb1.jpg","./catboy/cb2.jpg","./catboy/cb3.jpg","./catboy/cb4.jpg"];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    var randomImage = images[rand];
    console.log( randomImage )
    message.channel.send("rawr", randomImage);
}`